# How to do this half bright face effect for portraits?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

[image]
So you can have a look at that picture, in that picture, the middle men's face is half bright and half of normal colour.

How to do that effect using photoshop?
Please anyone if you know please elaborate in a step by step manner.

What is this effect named as?

Comment: @user568458 -- You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have the photographer take the photo with the light source on one side.

---

You can then *increase* the effect in Photoshop.

Take that photo of a face where the light source is on one side ([photo source](http://www.thisiscolossal.com/2013/11/facespics-twitter-account-posts-fun-anthropomorphic-photos-containing-hidden-faces/))...

[image]

...and increase the **contrast** using `Image > Adjustments > Brightness/Contrast`.

Or, a more advanced way with more fine control is to use  `Image > Adjustments > Curves` to create an `s` shaped curve where the darker parts of the face are darkened and the lighter parts lightened - find where on the curve the `s` should pivot with the eyedropper you get while the curves window is open.

[image]

This won't help unless the photo was taken with the light source on one side.